# MySQL query delivers wrong result when using <> (not equal) in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I came accross a strange problem with a MySQL Query

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM members
100

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM members WHERE lastname = 'Smith'
20

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM members WHERE lastname <> 'Smith'
0
```

**The problem is, that the last query (Members with lastname != 'Smith') returns 0.**

If there are 100 members in total and 20 members named 'Smith', the number of member with other last names should be 80, shouldn't it?

I tried different version using `<>`, `!=`, enclosing `Smith` with `'` or `"`. The result when using `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` instead is the same.

**How is this possible?** It seems that I am missing something quite obvious, but what...?

Comment: Try: count `where lastname is null` too...

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sql uses three-valued logic

Comment: Expanding on @jarlh 's comment, if the other 80 lastnames are `NULL`, they'll be automatically filtered-out with the simple `WHERE` clause, unless you specifically include them.

Comment: "Sql uses three-valued_logic " -> Meaning `WHERE lastname <=> 'Smith'` ... `<=>` is MySQL's NULL-safe equal check [operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)..

Comment: Share input output data sample first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because others are **null**

try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM members WHERE IFNULL(lastname ,'--')<> 'Smith'
```

**Example :**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
SELECT 'ersin' name  FROM dual
union all
SELECT 'ersin' name  FROM dual
union all
SELECT 'ersin' name  FROM dual
union all
SELECT null name  FROM dual
union all
SELECT null name  FROM dual
union all
SELECT null name  FROM dual;
```

**select script:**

```
select count(*) from my_table where IFNULL(name ,'--') <> 'ersin' ;
```

**output:**

```
count(*)
3
```

Comment: Ever heard of `<=>` ? See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

Comment: ANSI SQL has `lastname is distinct from 'Smith'`.